# How to create a Checkbox object in Android Studio with its own Action Listener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I already did it on java on which the JCheckbox object has it's own Action Listener and characteristics, here is a sample code in java..

```
private class checkBoxTask extends JCheckBox{

    checkBoxTask me;

    public checkBoxTask(){
        super();
        me = this;
        me.setText("task");
  }
}
```

But at Android Studio, I'm getting a 'super(Context context)' constructor that gave an error on adding the checkbox in the layout because i need to pass an argument value on it which is i don't know what.

```
class task extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox {

    task me;

    public task(Context context) {
        super(context);
        me=this;
        me.setText("task");
    }
  }

FloatingActionButton newTask = findViewById(R.id.newTask);

    newTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            LinearLayout taskLayout = findViewById(R.id.taskLayout);
            taskLayout.addView(new task()); //<-- here is where the 
   code wants me to put an argument
            logValue++;
        }
    });
```

Im still new to this, I'd like to know what can I do in that constructor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out now! thanks for Etoile..
I just pass the java class name as the context, here..

public void onClick(View view) {

```
            LinearLayout taskLayout = findViewById(R.id.taskLayout);
            taskLayout.addView(new task(MainActivity.this));
            logValue++;
        }
```

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got it working :) If my answer helped, please accept it, so it may help others in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to pass a *Context* argument (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context).

For example in fragment, you should get it like this:

```
Context mContext; // global variable

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
}
```

Or you can simply do this:

```
taskLayout.addView(new task(getContext));
```

Comment: I already tried putting the 'getContext' but it was not allowed instead i tried getBaseContext and getApplicationContext, though the checkbox did not appear in the app but it did occupy some space when srolling. As for creating a global variable it was the same also :(